# Why is Imgur rejecting my image upload?

Tags: support, imgur

Since yesterday I'm trying to answer some questions and add a descriptive image to the answer, but I get an error saying Imgur is rejecting the request:

[image: screenshot of the error message]

What's going on?

Comment: [Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609/164356)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes.

The issue is that imgur is dependent on Amazon AWS, which [were having problems](https://status.aws.amazon.com/):

[image: aws messages about their outage]

We don't know how long it will take imgur to resolve the issues they have been experiencing, but we hope it will not take long, now that AWS is back to usual operations.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukE8.png

Comment: clbuttic, isn't it?